# How can I move specific values from one field in a JSON column to another in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Let's assume I have a table users with a JSON column "foo". Values of that column look like this:

```
"{ field1: ['bar', 'bar2', 'bar3'], field2: ['baz', 'baz2', 'baz3'] }"
```

where field1 and field2 are optional, so column value may look like this: `"{}"`

I want to move values 'bar2' and 'bar3' from field1 to field2 for all records in this table.

Sample Output:

```
"{ field1: ['bar'], field2: ['baz', 'baz2', 'baz3', 'bar2', 'bar3']}"
```

More examples:

```
"{ field1: ['bar3'], field2: ['baz', 'baz2', 'baz3'] }"
```

should be transformed into

```
"{ field1: [], field2: ['baz', 'baz2', 'baz3', 'bar3'] }"
```

etc.

Is there any way to do this?

Unfortunately I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: How do you identify 'bar2' and 'bar3'? By name (bar2, bar3) or by position (2nd and 3rd element)?

Comment: Can you also provide some extra values (e.g. 4 extra records for both sample input and expected output) to show how it should behave on more complex use cases?

Comment: I identify bar2, bar3 by name. 

More examples: 
1. "{ field1: ['bar3'], field2: ['baz', 'baz2', 'baz3'] }" should be transformed into "{ field1: [], field2: ['baz', 'baz2', 'baz3', 'bar3'] }"
_____
2. { field1: ['bar3', 'bar2']}" should be transformed into "{ field1: [], field2: ['bar3', 'bar2'] }"

order of values is not important

Comment: A meta-answer: if you want to do things like that, you shouldn't have chosen a data model with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a series of subqueries with `jsonb_array_elements`

```
select jsonb_build_object('field1', coalesce((select jsonb_agg(v.value) 
       from jsonb_array_elements(u.foo -> 'field1') v 
       where v.value#>>'{}' not in ('bar2', 'bar3')), '[]'::jsonb),
   'field2', (u.foo -> 'field2') || (select jsonb_agg(v.value) 
       from jsonb_array_elements(u.foo -> 'field1') v 
       where v.value#>>'{}' in ('bar2', 'bar3'))) 
from users u 
where u.foo ? 'field1' and u.foo ? 'field2'
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pVNNSnHD)